# Find all possible paths in a directed cyclic graph

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, graph

I want to find all possible paths in a directed cyclic graph. I have written a program which does so, but I notice that if the number of nodes grow above 40 or 50, it starts taking infinite time.

Theoretically speaking how many paths are possible for a directed cyclic graph of **N** nodes. Is it like factorial(**N**) or something? Can you give me a guess for the following example with 119 nodes. Of course, I am going over loops only once, so you can ignore the cyclic paths.

[Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRACm.jpg)

Comment: I have tried Depth First search.

Comment: At this moment I am interested in knowing the theoretical limit.

Comment: Theoretical limit is based on the computer, architecture, and I could go on. Even up to compiler flags used. You need to analyze your algorithm in great detail. Start with small cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just take this common pattern that shows in your graph:

```
A ---> B
|     /|
|    / v
|   /  C
|  /   |
| /    |
vv    /
D <---
```

Excuse the ASCII art. So you have three paths here: `A -> D`, `A -> B -> D`, and `A -> B -> C -> D`.

Now say you have the exact same figure emanating from `D` to another node `G`:

```
D ---> E
|     /|
|    / v
|   /  F
|  /   |
| /    |
vv    /
G <---
```

You have the same analogous three paths as before: `D -> G`, `D -> E -> G`, and `D -> E -> F -> G`.

Now, how many paths are there from `A` to `G`?

To get from `A` to `G`, you have to get from `A` to `D`. You can do this in one of three ways. Then you have to get from `D` to `G`. You can do this in one of three ways. These two choices (`A` to `D` and `D` to `G`) are independent of each other. Thus you have `3` * `3` = `9` possible paths from `A` to `G`.

If you keep repeating the figure, you multiply the number of possible paths by `3` with each repetition. So with three figures, 27 paths; with four figures, 81 paths; etc.

That's exponential growth. Put differently: you'll have to find another way to do what it is you're doing, if you want to be efficient about it.

EDIT: To get a rough estimate: only counting those figures, not even looking at the complex jumbles in the middle, I get `3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * (2^8) * (4^8) * 3 * 3 * 2 * 3` = **`73383542784`** possible paths, through just those simple nodes.

EDIT: You seem to be doing code analysis. Without knowing exactly what you want to do, what I recommend is consolidating whatever information you're gathering along those nodes that *must* be reached (e.g. nodes `A`, `D`, and `G` in my example figures). Then do a search until you get to the next node that *must* be reached, and gather your info there as well. This will prevent exponential blow-up.

Comment: So it looks like he's in the O(n^2) or O(n^3) range?

Comment: More like b^n, where b is the branching factor, or the number of outgoing edges from a node.

Comment: Oh.. Right. Had my exponents/bases switched.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first train of though too, until I realized there _are_ an infinite number of paths.  Look at the second-to-last node in the chart.

Comment: @user1018562: no, that's the number of paths, "not even looking at the complex jumbles"

Comment: @MooingDuck: yea true, but he said he wasn't following loops so i assumed he'd just want to ignore that

Comment: @user1018562: **73383542784** is the _lowest possible estimate_ for the number of paths in the graph you supplied (119 nodes)

Comment: @MooingDuck There are a number of cycles in the graph, that last one is one of many.

Comment: That is true, I'm ignoring the loops.

Comment: @user1018562: but is your _algorithm_ ignoring those loops?

Comment: Mooing Duck: Yes it is ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- Find nodes in your graph that are part of every path. To do that, sequentially remove nodes from your graph. Each node that, if removed, makes it impossible to find a path is such a node. Your graph should have plenty of those.
- I can't prove this, but it should be possible to find an order in which those nodes appear in every path.
- Split the graph into chunks that consist of two consecutive forced nodes and all nodes between them
- Calculate the number of paths for each chunk
- Calculate  the product of all path counts to get the full count. Remember to use something like GMP to avoid overflowing  numbers